# Ubuntu PC configuration

Tags: compatibility, soundcard

I am planning a purchase of desktop components. I want them all to be compataible with Ubuntu (14.04 at the moment). 
I am not that good with hardware and i am not sure if all of the components will work with it. Can I get any piece of advice?

Plan:
sound : ASUS Xonar DX 7.1 Channels 24-bit 192KHz PCI Express x1 Interface Sound Card

video: GIGABYTE 2048M GTX960 N960IXOC-2GD

Motherboard: ASROCK Z170 Extreme4, DDR4 3200+(O.C)/2133, DVI, HDMI, DP, SATA III, M.2 Socket, SATA Express, USB 3.1, LGA1151

CPU: INTEL  CORE i7-6700K, 4.00GHz, 8MB, BOX, LGA1151, Skylake

RAM:    CRUCIAL 8GB DDR4 2133, CT8G4DFD8213

SSD:    ADATA   128GB M.2 2280 SSD SP900 X2 units

HDD: SEAGATE    2000GB 7200 64MB SATA III Barracuda, ST2000DM001

PSU: COOLER MASTER G650M, Bronze, Modular

CASE :  ZALMAN Z11 Plus, ATX, USB3.0 Black, w/o PSU

Sound card is a MUST. Any other option in the same money category is acceptable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a hardware recommendation question.

Comment: @FixXxeR did you build, and did it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu works with nearly all components that are not too exotic. You list components that are pretty common so it is likely that they'll work in Ubuntu. However no one can say for sure until you actually try it.